# How to write NFC tag if a specific URL is on it

Tags: node.js, xcode, nfc

I have an NFC app where at the moment the tags can be written only if its' serial number (UID) is on the backend of my system.

I am branching out and I would not be able to get the UID's of the new tags but I am able to encode it with a URL.

My question is how would I be able to now use the UIDs or having that URL as an authenticating system on my code. If authenticated, to go ahead and write the tag as normal. If not, does not write the NFC tag and come up with error message.

Answer (score 0):

"Authenticating" implies some level of security, where there is really no security with NFC.

While you can write your App to read the tag UID and URL from the data section of the Tag and check these against your requirements, there is little to stop people using Tags with changeable UID's to duplicate your Tags and bypass any "security" you think you have.

Comment: Hi Andrew, great I am glad that this would be possible. The authenticating is just to make sure that in most cases only the people who have purchased the tag through me would be able to write the tag using my app.

Comment: If I get the code for this, please would you be able to help me code it to add the URL checking?

Comment: There is too little info on the platforms you want to write this for, the hardware used as the reader and the make and model of the Tags being used. I suggest that you post another question with more precise details and what code you already have. Then answers can help you in more details. One pointer I will suggest is that you use the Ndef data format for storing the URL.